# Topological Space With Matrix Elements

Tags: general-topology, matrices, analysis, compactness, connectedness

Let $U$ denote the set of all $n\times n$ matrices $A$ with complex entries such that $A$ is unitary(i.e $A^* A=I_n$). Then $U$ is a topological subspace of $C^{n^2}$,then which of the following is true?

1.Compact,but not connected

2.Connected,but not compact

3.Connected and compact

4.Neither connected nor compact

Comment: I know the definition of comapct space only

Comment: Hint: For compactness one can use Heine–Borel by checking if $U$ is closed and bounded.

Comment: I can check whether any subset is closed or bounded when the elements are real numbers but I do not know how to check when the elements are matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is both compact and connected.

1. Compact, since every column of such matrix is unitary, and hence the matrix is bounded. In fact, $\|A\|_2=1$. The set is closed, as if $A_n$ are unitary and $A_n\to A$, then $A$ is also unitary.
2. Path Connectedness. If $A$ is a unitary matrix, then it can be written as 
   $$
   A=V^*\mathrm{diag}(\mathrm{e}^{ia_1},\ldots,\mathrm{e}^{ia_n})V
   $$
   Then, the following is a continuous curve in $U$:
   $$
   \varGamma(t)=V^*\mathrm{diag}(\mathrm{e}^{ia_1t},\ldots,\mathrm{e}^{ia_nt})V\in U
   $$
   and $\varGamma(1)=A$, while $\varGamma(0)=I$.